# Код на java без классов

Tags: java

Не могли бы вы мне показать пример программы на языке java без единого класса?
И что происходит, если при компиляции программы обнаруживается, что метод **main** отсутствует?

Comment: Напишите такой код да посмотрите что произойдёт, чо

Answer (score 12):

Ну вообще, код без классов не заработает, хоть один класс да должен быть. Возможно, Вы хотите увидеть код без единого метода:

```
public class Example {
    static {
        System.out.println("OLOLO");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Пример описан в книге Эккеля «Философия Java». 
Если закомментируете  `System.exit(0);`, код скомпилируется, но при выполнении сработает исключение `NoSuchMethodException`.

Comment: Видел пример в качестве какой-то узкопрофильной хохмы, java программа без единого класса. Тогда не обратил на это внимания и просто пролистал, а сейчас просто интересно вспомнить.

Answer (score 10):

[Java — сильно типизированный объектно-ориентированный язык программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java).

Исходя из того, что Java — *объектно-ориентированный* язык, а если без класса не может быть объекта, то ничего не получится.

> если при компиляции программы обнаруживается, что метод `main` отсутствует

Представьте, что вы хотите попасть в магазин, а там нету входной двери, что вы будете делать? (без фанатизма)

P.S. маленькие советы:

- начните читать книги (по мне [эта](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009205.do) самая простая для понимания),
- никогда не бойтесь спрашивать, лучше спросить и узнать, чем бояться спрашивать и не знать. НО! перед тем, как задать вопрос — старайтесь его сформулировать и всегда показывайте, что у вас не получается (а не «а-ля вот сделайте мне это»).

Comment: И магазина нет, и вас тоже нет...

Comment: @NickVolynkin Самое страшное это то, что мы этого никак не проверим :)

Answer (score 8):

1. Код вне классов в java не существует
2. для того, чтобы класс **скомпилировался**, main не нужен. Он нужен как точка входа для java-приложения.

В принципе, в библиотеках обычно не бывает метода main, что отнюдь не мешает их распространять и ими пользоваться.

Comment: `- С какого метода начинается выполнение программы на java?    
    - С метода Main, конечно же!    
    - А что, если метода main нет?    
    - ???`